# phonegap 3.5 and plugin for native transition how to integrate?

Tags: cordova, transition

i want to integrate this plugin in my phonegap ios app:
http://ilee.co.uk/native-page-transitions-with-phonegap/

But i don't understand how this to integrate in my html file?
I installed plugin, but i don't know how to call it?

Could someone help me how to call this transition in my phonegap html file?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Should be this.  They have a github demo project and this is how it is setup. Add this code below to your config.xml

gap:plugin name="uk.co.ilee.nativetransitions" version="0.1.3"

sorry there should be blockquotes to the above code

Comment: Thanks for help. You didn't understand me. I am interested how to integrate this plugin in my project. I now how to install with cordoba plugin command, but i don't know how to call it?

Comment: Same exact question. Documentation seems vague. Could someone provide an example? For example: to use a jquery mobile transition you insert data-transition="slide" in an anchor tag.

Answer (score 0):

The documentation you linked provides examples on how to use the library.

```
var duration = 0.5, 
    direction = "down";

setTimeout(function() {
// Change your html here
}, 50);
nativetransitions.flip(duration, direction);
```

Where it says `// Change your html here` you will use anchors or something similar to move the pages location or hide/show parts of your page.

For example

```
var duration = 0.5, 
    direction = "down";

setTimeout(function() {
   scrollTo(0, 500);
}, 50);
nativetransitions.flip(duration, direction);
```